# common character count challenge on Code signal

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

When I loop through both arrays I am getting a pass on most of the tests. One of the tests creates a problem as continues the nest loop against the first loop even when the matched element is removed.

Input:
s1: "abca"
s2: "xyzbac"

Heres my code:

```js
function commonCharacterCount(s1, s2) {
    const arrayOne = s1.split("")
    const arrayTwo = s2.split("")
    var matches = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arrayTwo.length; j++) {
            console.log(arrayTwo[j],arrayOne[i], matches)
           if (arrayOne[i] === arrayTwo[j]) {
               matches.push(arrayOne[i])
               arrayOne.splice(arrayOne[i], 1)
        
           }
        }
    }
    return matches.length
}
```

I checked the console log on test 3 which is the only one that is failing and I can see there is an issue skipping over the second item "b".

Answer (score 0):

Since you are slicing arrayOne you remove an item from arrayOne and this means that it will skip over an item because the variable i gets incremented by 1 but the arrayOne loses an item. So you get something like this.

```
arrayOne = ["a","b","c","d"]  
i = 0  
arrayOne[i] results to "a"
```

now you find a match with arrayTwo and you slice arrayOne at the index i of your match so arrayOne becomes

```
arrayOne = ["b","c","d"]  
//however you still increment i by one so i becomes  
i = 1  
//so now arrayOne[i] becomes  
arrayOne[i] results to "c"
```

Now I'm not sure my explanation is any good but I have two solutions. 1 doesn't splice and the other does but when it does it decrements i by one.

option 1

```
function commonCharacterCount(s1, s2) {
    const arrayOne = s1.split("")
    const arrayTwo = s2.split("")
    var matches = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arrayTwo.length; j++) {
            console.log(arrayTwo[j],arrayOne[i], matches)
           if (arrayOne[i] === arrayTwo[j]) {
               matches.push(arrayOne[i])        
           }
        }
    }
    return matches.length
}
```

option 2

```
function commonCharacterCount(s1, s2) {
    const arrayOne = s1.split("")
    const arrayTwo = s2.split("")
    var matches = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arrayTwo.length; j++) {
            console.log(arrayTwo[j],arrayOne[i], matches)
           if (arrayOne[i] === arrayTwo[j]) {
               matches.push(arrayOne[i])
               arrayOne.splice(arrayOne[i], 1)
               i--
           }
        }
    }
    return matches.length
}
```